# How to Override the ProductRepository class

Tags: magento-2.1, overrides

I want to override the `ProductRepository.php` class need to do some `changes` in the Save function

File Path : `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php`

Fucntion Name: Save

How can I Override the `ProductRepository.php` class which is implement by the  `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` class

Our magento2 version is: 2.1.7

Answer (score 3):

You can either you preference or plugin for this issue.

**Use preference:**

Step 1: Create a file extending **\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository** class in your module:

```
<?php
namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;

class ProductRepository extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
{
 public function save(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product, $saveOptions = false)
 {
        \\ Your implementation
 }

}
```

Step 2: paste this line to file di.xml in app/code/YourNamespace/YourModule/etc folder:

```
<preference for="\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository" type="YourNamespace\YourModule\Model\ProductRepository"/>
```

**Use plugin:**

Step 1: Create plugin class for ProductRepository:

```
<?php
namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Plugin;

class ProductRepositoryPlugin
{

   public function aroundSave(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $origin,
    $proceed,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product, 
    $saveOptions = false
   )
   {

   }
}
```

Step 2: Copy these lines to file di.xml in app/code/YourNamespace/YourModule/etc folder:

```
<type name="\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository">
    <plugin name="override_class_by_plugin" type="\YourNamespace\YourModule\Plugin\ProductRepositoryPlugin" />
</type>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use Plugin for ***`change behavior of the  class functions by
>   intercepting save() function call and running code before, after, or
>   around that function call`.***

See the use for source how to use plugin

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-plugin-interceptor.html

First you should create a module which have di.xml at `app/code/etc/[Vendorname]/[Module]`

**di.xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository">
        <plugin name="change_behavior_of" type="[Vendorname]\[Module]\Plugin\ProductRepositoryPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Plugin Class**

Then plugin class `ProductRepositoryPlugin.php` is located at `app/code/etc/[Vendorname]/[Module]/Plugin`

```
<?php
namespace [Vendorname]\[Module]\Plugin;
class ProductRepositoryPlugin
{

}
```