# How to override ProductRepository model file in Magento2?

Tags: model, override-model

I need to override **processMediaGallery** method from

> \vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\ProductRepository.php

I used below code in my custom module **etc/di.xml**.

< preference for="\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository" type="YourNamespace\YourModule\Model\ProductRepository" />

And added the ProductRepository.php file into my custom module Model folder of module-catalog from the vendor.

I am getting below error after doing this.

ProductFactory does not exist in [Bms\Shop\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor]

Have anyone faced the same issue?

Comment: Please add the di.xml code and code your are using in your overridden file.

Comment: Ref : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188064/how-to-override-the-productrepository-class/188067

Comment: Hi, that is not working followed the same but throwing error.